# Não consigo converter arquivos mongodb para json no python usando o bson em python

Tags: python, json, mongodb, conversão

Eu to tentando trabalhar com dados de um banco de dados mongo online. To conseguindo fazer as requisições da forma correta. Mas ao tentar converter os dados baixados usando o pacote bson, eu recebo um objeto string e não um json. Tentei de várias formas converter esse string em json, mas não consegui. Como faço essa conversão?

Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

```
from bson.json_util import dumps

.
.
.

dados = colecao.find_one()
ver_json = dumps(dados)
print(ver_json)

>>> '{"_id": {"$oid": "602e6c108a0e449623b9ffd6"}, "cidades": "Maceio", "longitude": 35.5878, "latitude": -9.0, "data": {"$date": 1613617200000}, "temperaturaAr": 25.1, "precipitacao": 2.0, "radiacao": 560.0, "velocidadeVento": 10.0, "direcaoVento": 234.0}'

type(ver_json)
>>> str
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *eu recebo um objeto string e não um json*

Vale lembrar que JSON não é um "tipo", é somente um [formato de dados](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). O que as API's fazem é mapear este formato para estruturas próprias de cada linguagem. No caso do Python, já foi mencionado a [tabela de conversão](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json-to-py-table), e nela vemos que no seu caso, um objeto JSON (delimitado por `{ }`) é mapeado para um [dicionário](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping).

Então na verdade você não precisava ter convertido para string. Bastava usar o retorno de `find_one`, que já é o dicionário que você precisa (pois este dicionário já representa o JSON em questão):

```
dados = colecao.find_one()
print(dados) # imprime o documento
print(type(dados)) # <class 'dict'>
```

---

O que a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/495699/112052) sugeriu funciona, claro, mas **é uma volta desnecessária**: não há motivo para transformar `dados` em string, para depois transformar esta string em `dict` novamente. Até porque no fim, os dicionários gerados serão iguais:

```
from bson.json_util import dumps
dados = colecao.find_one()
# transforma dados em string
ver_json = dumps(dados)

# transforma a string em dicionário
import json
entidade = json.loads(ver_json)
print(dados == entidade) # True (os dicionários são iguais)
```

Ou seja, não precisa de nada disso. Se quer um dicionário, use o que foi retornado por `find_one` e pronto. Usar `dumps` só faz sentido se você realmente precisa desses dados em uma única string. Caso não precise, é desnecessário fazer tudo isso.

Answer (score 2):

Para fazer o cast do str para um dict, basta importar a lib [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) que faz parte da biblioteca padrão do python para fazer encode e decode de JSON.

> A função loads desserializa uma string ou array de bytes (contendo
> json) para um objeto python seguindo a [tabela de conversão](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json-to-py-table).

Tabela de conversão:

| JSON | Python |
| --- | --- |
| object | dict |
| array | list |
| string | str |
| number(int) | int |
| number(real) | float |
| true | True |
| false | False |
| null | None |

Segue um exemplo:

```
import json
#utilizando o json que forneceu na pergunta
a = '{"_id": {"$oid": "602e6c108a0e449623b9ffd6"}, "cidades": "Maceio", "longitude": 35.5878, "latitude": -9.0, "data": {"$date": 1613617200000}, "temperaturaAr": 25.1, "precipitacao": 2.0, "radiacao": 560.0, "velocidadeVento": 10.0, "direcaoVento": 234.0}'

entidade = json.loads(a)
entidade['_id']
#{'$oid': '602e6c108a0e449623b9ffd6'}
type(entidade)
#<class 'dict'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenho dificuldade de testar mas bson tem uma função de conversão directa.
Portanto devia ser possivel fazeres:

```
import bson

dados = colecao.find_one()
d = beson.decode(dados)
print(d)                    ## e d seria tipo 'dict'
```